# Master page url is appended as prefix to anchor href in sharepoint 2013

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I've a master page (.html) file in SharePoint 2013. Inside this, I am generating global navigation. So, I have the HTML written and an Angular controller which fetches data from a list and binds it to this HTML to generate the navigation.

The issue is:

The master page library URL is prefixed before the actual URL. So instead of `http://sitecollectionurl/Pages/MyPage.aspx`, the URL is generated as: `http://sitecollectionurl/_catalogs/masterpage/branding/http://sitecollectionurl/Pages/MyPage.aspx`

Any ideas for this issue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could always use a site collection token in your URL.

```
~sitecollection
```

[URLs and tokens in SharePoint 2013](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms431831.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

If that don't work out for you, this blog post has a lot of great examples when working with masterpages and references. [Use Site Url in SharePoint](http://ethan-deng.blogspot.se/2013/06/use-site-url-in-sharepoint.html)

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need this?

```
<SharePoint:CssRegistration name="&lt;% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/css/style.css %&gt;" runat="server"  />
```